# Model properties are null when the form is submitted

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

On an ASP.NET MVC 5 project I have the following model:

```
public class ScheduleIndexModel {

  public IPageList<DataModel> Data { get; set; }
  public FormModel Form { get; set; }

  public class DataModel {
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }
    public String[] Attendees { get; set; }
    public String Location { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
  } // DataModel

  public class FormModel {      
    public String Location { get; set; }
    public String Date { get; set; }      
  } // FormModel

}
```

The view is the following:

```
<form action="@Url.Action(MVC.Schedule.Index())" method="post">
  @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Form.Date, "Date")
  @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Form.Date)
  @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Form.Location, "Location")
  @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Form.Location)
  @Html.SubmitButton("Filter", "Index", new { @class = "submit" })
  @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
</form>
```

Then the HTTPPost controller action is as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
public virtual ActionResult Index(ScheduleIndexModel.FormModel model, Int32 p = 1) {
  return View();
} // Index
```

When I submit the form the model is not null but its properties are even if I write something on the TextBoxes.

Does anyone knows what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is your model in the view `@model ScheduleIndexModel` or `@model FormModel`. If the former (I suspect it is), then it should be `ActionResult Index(ScheduleIndexModel model)` (or use `[Bind(Prefix=`

Comment: It is @model ScheduleIndexModel ... So to use FormModel in my action I need Bind(Prefix? what is the value od the PRefix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to use a binding prefix because your viewmodel is nested.  Something like this may work:

```
public virtual ActionResult Index([Bind(Prefix = "Form")] FormModel model)
```

Comment: I tried it and in that case the FormModel becomes null when submitting the form ...

Comment: The prefix should be Form and not ScheduleIndexModel. Other than that, this is the solution. Could you update your answer so I can mark it as answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your html helpers (e.g. `@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Form.Date)` will be generating html like this

```
<input name="Form.Date" .../>
```

but because your post method accepts parameter of type `FormModel` it cant match up (`FormModel` only has property `Date`, not property `Form` that has property `Date`).

You can either change you action method to

```
public virtual ActionResult Index(ScheduleIndexModel model,... 
{
  FormModel form = model.Form; // get the FormModel
```

or use the `[Bind(Prefix..)]` as suggested by Big Daddy